# Py-Cord command runs 3 times

Tags: discord, pycord

I have a command to DM a user anonymously and log the interaction:

````py
@bot.command(name = "dmuser", description = "Send an anonymous DM to a user")
@guild_only()
async def dmuser(ctx, user: discord.Option(discord.Member, "Who to send the DM to?"), msg):
    if ctx.author.id in blocked_users_dmuser:
        await ctx.respond("Hm, it seems like you don't have permission to run this. Please contact TheMineCommander#5367 or use /support if you believe this is an error.", ephemeral=True)
        return
    elif user not in ctx.guild.members:
        await ctx.respond("This user is not in your guild.",ephemeral=True)
        return
    else:
        dmchannel = await bot.create_dm(user)
        uuid = random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=20)
        uuid = ''.join(uuid)
        msg = msg.replace("\\n", "\n")
        await dmchannel.send(f"You got an anonymous DM from **{ctx.guild}**!\n--\n```\n{msg}\n```\n--\nIf you would like to report this message, please contact TheMineCommander#5367.\nThe message UUID is `{uuid}`.")
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            webhook = discord.Webhook.from_url('https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1091580748131217519/URL CUT OUT FOR SECURITY', session=session)
            await webhook.send(f"Author: {ctx.author.id}, {ctx.author.name}\nFrom server: {ctx.guild.name}, {ctx.guild.id}\nRecipient: {user},\nUUID: {uuid}\n\n\n```\n{msg}\n```")
        await ctx.respond("Sent DM!", ephemeral=True)
````

However, it DMs three times and logs it three times. Why is this?

I only expected it to run once.

Comment: This can happen if you are running multiple instances of the bot. Is this the case?

Comment: LMAO that was the case, turns out Sublime Text keeps running the program even after being closed

Comment: This question will most likely be closed as not being reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had run the bot 3 times